# How to output the most common value but not if it is evenly common with something else

Tags: excel, text, google-sheets, spreadsheet

There is a column `Values` with a number of `Strings`, then show below the most common value and the number of occurrences of that value (i.e. mode of `Strings`). Here's an example.

`+--------+
 | Values |
 +--------+
 |   AA   |
 +--------+
 |   BB   |
 +--------+
 |   AA   |
 +--------+
 |   AA   |
 +--------+
 |   GG   |
 +--------+
 |   DD   |
 +--------+
 |   DD   |
 +--------+
 |        |
 +-----------------+--------+
 |   Most Common   |   AA   |
 +-----------------+--------+`

But I do want that if there are multiple instances that occur the same amount of times that it shows something else. Here's an example.

`+--------+
 | Values |
 +--------+
 |   AA   |
 +--------+
 |   BB   |
 +--------+
 |   CC   |
 +--------+
 |   AA   |
 +--------+
 |   GG   |
 +--------+
 |   DD   |
 +--------+
 |   DD   |
 +--------+
 |        |
 +-----------------+--------+
 |   Most Common   |  none  |
 +-----------------+--------+`

Comment: In Excel or Google Spreadsheets?

Answer (score 0):

A Google Spreadsheet formula based solution:

```
=ArrayFormula(COUNTIF($A$3:$A$7, UNIQUE(A3:A7)))
```

Gives us the counts of the different unique elements

---

```
={UNIQUE(A3:A7), ArrayFormula(COUNTIF($A$3:$A$7, UNIQUE(A3:A7)))}
```

gives us a frequency table of the different values.

---

```
QUERY({UNIQUE(A3:A7), ArrayFormula(COUNTIF($A$3:$A$7, UNIQUE(A3:A7)))}, 
      "SELECT Col1 WHERE Col2 = " & MAX(ArrayFormula(COUNTIF($A$3:$A$7, UNIQUE(A3:A7)))), 
      0)
```

Gives us the most frequent Element(s). We Query the fields once and filter the counts

---

```
=IF(COUNTA(QUERY({UNIQUE(A3:A7), ArrayFormula(COUNTIF($A$3:$A$7, UNIQUE(A3:A7)))}, 
                 "SELECT Col1 WHERE Col2 = " & MAX(ArrayFormula(COUNTIF($A$3:$A$7, UNIQUE(A3:A7)))), 
                 0)) > 1, 
    "none",
    QUERY({UNIQUE(A3:A7), ArrayFormula(COUNTIF($A$3:$A$7, UNIQUE(A3:A7)))}, 
          "SELECT Col1 WHERE Col2 = " & MAX(ArrayFormula(COUNTIF($A$3:$A$7, UNIQUE(A3:A7)))), 0))
```

Gives us "none" if there are more the two most frequent elements the most frequent element otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure whether this also works in Google Sheets, but for Excel, assuming a range of `A1:A7`:

`=IF(COUNT(MODE.MULT(MATCH(A1:A7,A1:A7,0)))>1,"None",INDEX(A1:A7,MODE(MATCH(A1:A7,A1:A7,0))))`

Regards